# A Trivial Pursuit #18 (Sports and Leisure 3/4): Connected

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, connect-wall, metapuzzles, sports

<sub>This is part 18 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

Sometimes one [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle just isn't enough... so I hereby present PSE's first (and probably last) **connecting wall of connecting walls**!

Below are 16 different connecting walls, each of which can be resolved into 4 connected groups of 4 items. Crucially, in each case **at least one group is related to sports or board/card games**. For each wall, there is a hidden word (not included in the list) that can fit into all 4 groups. Together, these 16 hidden words themselves form a final 4x4 connecting meta-wall whose *one-word category descriptions* can themselves be linked to a final hidden word - *this is the final answer for the whole puzzle*.

Note that due to the sheer size of this puzzle, I have ensured that the walls are generally not as 'devious' or 'tricksy' as the typical connecting wall presented by itself; however, they should still present a challenge (and hopefully an enjoyable one at that). I am fully expecting this puzzle to be solved through collaboration - **partial answers are welcome as long as they comprise fully completed connecting walls, with justification** (please no partial groups or incompletely solved walls).

*Can you find the hidden word?* Ready? Steady? Go!

Hint for the meta-wall:

> There is a sporting connection in this wall too, involving four sportsmen who share a first name. All are known for different sports. Two are British, two are Australian.

Wall 01:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | BOFF | BOPPER | CHIN |
| DEADWOOD | GUNSLINGER | HOMESTEADERS | PHIL |
| POW | REVOLVER | SHORT | SING |
| SLEEP | SOCK | THWACK | UNIT |

Wall 02:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BALL | BANKS | BILBAO | BURNLEY |
| CLUB | COMPOUND | DOVER | HUNT |
| MOORE | OLDHAM | SEARCHLIGHT | SILVERSTONE |
| SINGER | TORCHBEARER | TROUNCE | WHOLEGRAIN |

Wall 03:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AWL | BACK | DEAL | FINAL |
| JACK | JANE | JOY | JUNK |
| LURK | MARK | MASTER | NOTE |
| NOVA | STARK | SUIT | TRICK |

Wall 04:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APHID | BRAEBURN | BREAK | CAMEO |
| CANDLE | CATHOLIC | EARHOLE | ENCOUNTER |
| FUJI | GALA | HOLIDAY | KEMP |
| SMUG | SOUTH | THIS PLANET | TIBETANS |

Wall 05:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DAMN | EXTRA | FIG | FINGER |
| HALF | HOB | HOOT | INJURY |
| JIMMY | JINX | MINGLE | OVER |
| RUSTY | SUITE | TANGY | TOSS |

Wall 06:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BATTLESHIP | CHARM | CROWN | CYCLOPS |
| FALCON | GULLIBLE | HOT SPOT | HULK |
| NEBULA | NUCLEAR | PAPERCLIP | SNICKO |
| TERNARY | TITLE | VAR | VISION |

Wall 07:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUNKED | CLASP | FOLD | GREEK |
| JOIN | MARTIN | OUTRAGED | PREMATURE |
| PROUD | ROUGE | SHAKE | STINGRAY |
| STRIPE | TEN | WARMING | WIFE |

Wall 08:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALERT | BRA | CARD | COUCH |
| DEVILS | GO | INGLES | JACKET |
| LICE | MASH | NEW | PIN |
| RUM | SWEET | TAN | YANK |

Wall 09:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CIAO | FRAU | HOO | HULL |
| HUNT | LAWSON | MAJOR | MCDAVID |
| MOORE | ORR | OSBORNE | PLOUGH |
| WATT | WEAR | WOW | Y |

Wall 10:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BALDING | BARKER | BREA | CORNERSHOP |
| CYPRESS | KILMARNOCK | LARGS | LOGAN |
| MONTROSE | ORANGE | PRIVY | SALTCOATS |
| SCOTT | SICILIANA | TROON | WESTMINSTER |

Wall 11:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOOK | BOSNICH | BOWLBY | DIEHL |
| FEDERICI | FILAN | FUNNINESS | KIMBLE |
| MCAVOY | NETWORK | RYAN | SCHWARZER |
| SOLO | STENT | WEIGHTED | WHITFIELD |

Wall 12:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACTIVE | CURE | DRY | DUMMY |
| FIT | GUN | HAMMER | HIGH |
| HOME | LIFE | PLEASURE | POLE |
| RAT | SHOT | SPEED | VINCE |

Wall 13:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALASKA | BOSTON | CENTRAL | DIRT |
| EASTERN | EXERCISE | GHOST | KANSAS |
| KISS | PACIFIC | POPEYE | PUSH |
| RAINBOW | RICEPAPER | SAKAGUCHI | SHAWL |

Wall 14:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BIRD | COACH | COSTCO | COTTAGE |
| COUNTER | DOCTOR | GENERAL | HUNGER |
| JIFFY | MINUTE | MOMENT | PROMOTER |
| REFEREE | SHAKE | SINCERE | TANGERINE |

Wall 15:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AIR | CHAMPION | FIELDS | FLINT |
| FURY | GEORGE | GOLD | HERCULES |
| HOOK | KENNEDY | O’BRIEN | PODOLOFF |
| SHAKESPEARE | SPARROW | STERN | TORNADO |

Wall 16:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BICYCLE | BIND | CORNER | FENCE |
| FIX | FREE | GOAL | JAM |
| OPTS | PICKLE | POST | ROPES |
| RUN | STOP | TAKE | TOPS |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This community wiki answer serves to compile all wall solutions into one complete answer, crediting those users who were first to find them...*

The final answer to the puzzle (found by @DanielS) is:

> **STEADY**

The is found by resolving the following connecting wall, which comprises the hidden words from each of the 16 individual walls:

> BANG, CHARLTON, DECK, EMPIRE, HANG, HAWKEYE, HOLD, HOT, HOWE, IRVINE, JONES, LONG, MOUNTAIN, SECOND, SILVER, SPOT
>
>  Its groups are:
>
>  **(Sports) Group 1 - Sportsmen named 'EDDIE':** [CHARLTON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Charlton) (cue sports), [HOWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Howe) (football), [IRVINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Irvine) (motor racing), [JONES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Jones_(rugby_union)) (rugby union);
>  **Group 2 - Words that precede 'ON':** BANG on, HANG on, HOLD on, SPOT on;
>  **Group 3 - Words that precede 'HAND':** [DECKhand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deckhand), [HOT hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_hand), [LONGhand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longhand), SECOND-hand;
>  **Group 4 - US STATE nicknames:** EMPIRE (NY), HAWKEYE (IO), MOUNTAIN (WV), SILVER (NV).
>
>  *Hidden word:* ON, EDDIE, HAND and STATE can all be preceded by **STEADY** (Steady on, "[Steady Eddie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/steady_Eddie)", Steady hand, Steady state).

The sixteen initial walls resolve as follows:

Wall 01 (solved by @JS1)

> **(Games) Group 1 - Western-themed board/card games:** [DEADWOOD](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/96713/deadwood), [GUNSLINGER](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1044/gunslinger), [HOMESTEADERS](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/26566/homesteaders), [REVOLVER](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/76150/revolver);
>  **Group 2 - "The Big ...":** APPLE, [BOPPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bopper), [SHORT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Short_(film)), [SLEEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Sleep);
>  **Group 3 - *Batman* TV series [onomatopoeia](https://batman60stv.fandom.com/wiki/Onomatopoeia):** BOFF, POW, SOCK, THWACK;
>  **Group 4 - First 4 letters of an Asian country:** CHIN(a), PHIL(ippines), SING(apore), UNIT(ed Arab Emirates).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **BANG**
>  (A Western-themed [game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3955/bang), The Big BANG, BANG!, BANG(ladesh))

Wall 02 (solved by @MOehm)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Football clubs missing 'ATHLETIC':** [Athletic BILBAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletic_Bilbao), [Athletic CLUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletic_Bilbao), [DOVER Athletic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dover_Athletic_F.C.), [OLDHAM Athletic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldham_Athletic_A.F.C.);
>  **(Sports) Group 2 - England players in the [1966 World Cup Final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup_final#Details):** Alan BALL, Gordon BANKS, Roger HUNT, Bobby MOORE;
>  **Group 3 - Words that end with an imperial unit of weight:** COM(POUND), SILVER(STONE), TR(OUNCE), WHOLE(GRAIN);
>  **Group 4 - Words that start with a synonym of 'damage by fire':** (BURN)LEY, (SEAR)CHLIGHT, (SINGE)R, (TORCH)BEARER.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **CHARLTON**
>  ([CHARLTON Athletic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlton_Athletic_F.C.), Bobby & Jack CHARLTON, CHARL(TON), (CHAR)LTON)

Wall 03 (solved by @JS1)

> **(Games) Group 1 - Card game terminology:** DEAL, JACK, SUIT, TRICK;
>  **Group 2 - Replace a vowel to form the name of a bird:** AWL (owl), JOY (jay), LURK (lark), STARK (stork);
>  **Group 3 - Words that can follow 'QUARTER':** quarterBACK, quarter-FINAL, quarterMASTER, quarter NOTE;
>  **Group 4 - 3-letter month abbreviations, plus a letter**: (JAN)E, (JUN)K, (MAR)K, (NOV)A.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **DECK**
>  (A pack of cards, one vowel away from DuCK, [quarterDECK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarterdeck) and (DEC)K)

Wall 04 (solved by @GarethMcCaughan and JS1)

> **(Games) Group 1 - Can follow the name of a [Monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)) space:** (Jail) BREAK, (Chance) ENCOUNTER, (Go) SOUTH, (Just Visiting) THIS PLANET ([book](https://neildegrassetyson.com/books/1998-07-just-visiting-this-planet/) / [film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099909/) / [album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Visiting_This_Planet));
>  **Group 2 - Contains a letter of the Greek alphabet at its centre:** A(PHI)D, EA(RHO)LE, S(MU)G, TI(BETA)NS;
>  **Group 3 - Apple varieties:** BRAEBURN, CAMEO, FUJI, GALA;
>  **Group 4 - Words that follow 'ROMAN':** Roman CANDLE, Roman CATHOLIC, [Roman HOLIDAY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Roman%20holiday), [Roman KEMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Kemp).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **EMPIRE**
>  ([Boardwalk EMPIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boardwalk_Empire), EM(PI)RE, [EMPIRE apples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_(apple)), Roman EMPIRE)

Wall 05 (solved by @Alaiko)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - When followed by 'TIME', a sporting concept:** EXTRA time, HALF time, INJURY time, OVERtime;
>  **Group 2 - Words that start with a historical Chinese dynasty**: ([JIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(1115%E2%80%931234)))X, ([MING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty))LE, ([SUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_dynasty))TE, ([TANG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tang_dynasty))Y;
>  **Group 3 - Words that can follow "don't give a ..." to mean that you couldn't care less:** DAMN, FIG, HOOT, TOSS;
>  **Group 4 - Words that can be followed by 'NAIL':** (FINGER)nail, (HOB)nail, [JIMMY nail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Nail), RUSTY nail.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **HANG**
>  ([Hang time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_time), [Han Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty), "don't give a hang", [hangnail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangnail))

Wall 06 (solved by @MOehm)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Referee assistance technology:** CYCLOPS (tennis), HOT SPOT (cricket), SNICKO (cricket), VAR (football);
>  **Group 2 - Words that start with a bird:** (CROW)N, (GULL)IBLE, (TERN)ARY, (TIT)LE;
>  **Group 3 - Words that end with a 3-letter body part:** BATTLES(HIP), CH(ARM), NUCL(EAR), PAPERC(LIP);
>  **Group 4 - [Marvel Cinematic Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) superheroes:** FALCON, HULK, NEBULA, VISION.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **HAWKEYE**
>  ([HAWK-EYE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawk-Eye) in tennis, (HAWK)EYE, HAWK(EYE), [Clint Barton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clint_Barton_(Marvel_Cinematic_Universe)))

Wall 07 (solved by @MOehm)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Parts of a golf course with their last letter changed:** BUNKED/r, GREEK/n, ROUGE/h, TEN/e;
>  **Group 2 - Words that can follow 'HOUSE':** [house MARTIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_house_martin), house-PROUD, houseWARMING, houseWIFE;
>  **Group 3 - Actions you can do to HANDS:** CLASP, FOLD, JOIN, SHAKE;
>  **Group 4 - Words that end with a synonym of 'OLD':** OUTR(AGED), PRE(MATURE), STIN(GRAY), ST(RIPE).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **HOLD**
>  (HOLD/e, houseHOLD, HOLD hands, H(OLD))

Wall 08 (solved by @MOehm)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Prepending an 'S' makes a tennis term:** (s)INGLES, (s)LICE, (s)MASH, (s)PIN;
>  **Group 2 - Words that can follow 'RED':** Red ALERT, Red CARD, [Red DEVILS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_United_F.C.#:%7E:text=The%20devil%20stems%20from%20the,of%20the%20shirt%20until%201971.), [Red RUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Rum);
>  **Group 3 - Words that can precede 'POTATO':** COUCH potato, JACKET potato, NEW potato, SWEET potato;
>  **Group 4 - Codewords of the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) two letters short:** BRA(vo), GO(lf), TAN(go), YANK(ee).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **HOT**
>  ((s)HOT, Red HOT, HOT potato, HOT(el))

Wall 09 (solved by @fljx)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Multiple-time winners of the NHL's [Art Ross Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Ross_Trophy):** [Bobby HULL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Hull), [Connor MCDAVID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connor_McDavid), [Dickie MOORE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickie_Moore_(ice_hockey)), [Bobby ORR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Orr);
>  **Group 2 - UK Chancellors of the Exchequer:** [Jeremy HUNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Hunt), [Nigel LAWSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Lawson), [John MAJOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Major), [George OSBORNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Osborne);
>  **Group 3 - Words that rhyme with 'OW':** CIAO, FRAU, PLOUGH, WOW;
>  **Group 4 - Homophones of question words:** HOO (Who?), WATT (What?), WEAR (Where?), Y (Why?).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **HOWE**
>  ([Gordie Howe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordie_Howe), [Geoffrey Howe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Howe), rhymes with 'OW', and sounds like 'How?')

Wall 10 (solved by @Alaiko)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Female BBC sports presenters:** [Sue BARKER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sue_Barker), [Clare BALDING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clare_Balding), [Gabby LOGAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabby_Logan), [Alex SCOTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Scott_(footballer,_born_1984));
>  **Group 2 - Towns in Ayrshire, Scotland:** KILMARNOCK, LARGS, SALTCOATS, TROON;
>  **Group 3 - Names end with climbing plants:** CORNERS(HOP), MONT(ROSE), PR(IVY), SICI(LIANA);
>  **Group 4 - Cities in [Orange County, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_County,_California#Communities):** BREA, CYPRESS, ORANGE, WESTMINSTER.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **IRVINE**
>  ([Hazel IRVINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazel_Irvine), a [town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irvine,_North_Ayrshire) in Ayrshire, IR(VINE), a [city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irvine,_California) in Orange County)

Wall 11 (solved by @MOehm)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Australian goalkeepers who played in the Premier League:** [Mark BOSNICH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Bosnich), [Adam FEDERICI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Federici), [John FILAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Filan), [Mark SCHWARZER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Schwarzer);
>  **Group 2 - Contains a number written out:** FUN(NINE)SS, NE(TWO)RK, S(TEN)T, W(EIGHT)ED;
>  **Group 3 - Surnames of actors whose first names are months:** [April BOWLBY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Bowlby), [August DIEHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Diehl), [May MCAVOY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_McAvoy), [June WHITFIELD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/June_Whitfield);
>  **Group 4 - Harrison Ford characters:** [John BOOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(1985_film)), [Richard KIMBLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fugitive_(1993_film)), [Jack RYAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Ryan_(franchise)), [Han SOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Solo).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **JONES**
>  ([Brad JONES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Jones_(soccer)), J(ONE)S, [January JONES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_Jones), [Indiana JONES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_(character)))

Wall 12 (solved by @JS1)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - First words of athletics field events:** HAMMER (throw), HIGH (jump), POLE (vault), SHOT (put);
>  **Group 2 - Words that can be prefixed by 'PRO' to form other words:** proACTIVE, proCURE, proFIT, proVINCE;
>  **Group 3 - Words that can precede 'RUN':** DRY run, DUMMY run, HOME run, RAT run;
>  **Group 4 - Words that can precede 'BOAT':** [GUNboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunboat), LIFEboat, PLEASURE boat, SPEEDboat.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **LONG**
>  (LONG jump, proLONG, LONG run, [LONGboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longboat))

Wall 13 (solved by @Alaiko)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Words that start with the surname of a player in England's national [men's football team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England_national_football_team#Players):** (POPE)YE (Nick Pope), (RICE)PAPER (Declan Rice), (SAKA)GUCHI (Bukayo Saka), (SHAW)L (Luke Shaw);
>  **Group 2 - [US time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States#United_States_and_regional_time_zones):** ALASKA, CENTRAL, EASTERN, PACIFIC;
>  **Group 3 - Words that can be followed by 'BIKE'**: DIRT bike, EXERCISE bike, [GHOST bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_bike), PUSH bike;
>  **Group 4 - Rock bands:** [BOSTON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_(band)), [KANSAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_(band)), [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_(band)), [RAINBOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_(rock_band)).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **MOUNTAIN**
>  ([Mason (MOUNT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_Mount)ain, [MOUNTAIN time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone), MOUNTAIN bike, and there is a band named [MOUNTAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_(band)))

Wall 14 (solved by @fljx)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Personnel involved in a boxing match:** COACH, DOCTOR, PROMOTER, REFEREE;
>  **Group 2 - Short periods of time:** JIFFY, MINUTE, MOMENT, SHAKE;
>  **Group 3 - Words that start with a [trigonometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions):** (COS)TCO, (COT)TAGE, (SIN)CERE, (TAN)GERINE;
>  **Group 4 - Words that can be followed by 'STRIKE':** BIRD strike, COUNTER-strike, GENERAL strike, HUNGER strike.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **SECOND**
>  (Boxing's [cornerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornerman), one sixtieth of a minute, (SEC)OND, [Second strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_strike))

Wall 15 (solved by @fljx)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - [NBA Commissioners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commissioner_of_the_NBA):** Walter KENNEDY, Larry O’BRIEN, Maurice PODOLOFF, David STERN;
>  **Group 2 - Medals:** [AIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Medal), [FIELDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal), [GEORGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Medal), GOLD;
>  **Group 3 - Fictional pirate captains:** FLINT (Treasure Island), HOOK (Peter Pan), SPARROW (Pirates of the Caribbean), **SHAKESPEARE** (Stardust);
>  **Group 4 - Horses from TV shows:** CHAMPION ([*Champion the Wonder Horse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champion_the_Wonder_Horse)), FURY ([*Fury*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fury_(American_TV_series))), HERCULES ([*Steptoe and Son*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steptoe_and_Son)), TORNADO ([*Zorro*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorro)).
>
>  *Hidden word:* **SILVER**
>  ([Adam SILVER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Silver), SILVER medal, Long John SILVER, and the horse from [*The Lone Ranger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Ranger))

Wall 16 (solved by @JS1)

> **(Sports) Group 1 - Types of 'KICK; in football**: BICYCLE, CORNER, FREE, GOAL;
>  **Group 2 - "In trouble" when "In a ...":** BIND, FIX, JAM, PICKLE;
>  **Group 3 - "On the ...":** FENCE, ROPES, RUN, TAKE;
>  **Group 4 - Anagrams of each other:** OPTS, POST, STOP, TOPS.
>
>  *Hidden word:* **SPOT**
>  (SPOT kick, in a SPOT, on the SPOT, anagram of POTS)

Answer (score 7):

Wall 02:

> "Athletic ...": **Bilbao**, **Dover**, **Club**, **Oldham**
>  ends in an imperial unit of weight:
>     **com·pound**, **tr·ounce**,  **whole·grain**, **silver·stone**
>  starts with destruction by fire:
>     **Burn·ley**, **sear·chlight**, **singe·r**, **torch·bearer**
>  England players in the 1966 World Cup final: **Ball**, **Banks**, **Hunt**, **Moore**
>
>  Linking word: **CHARLTON**

Wall 06:

> starts with a bird: **crow·n**, **gull·ible**, **tern·ary**, **tit·le**
>  referee assistance technology:
>      **Cyclops** (tennis), **Hot Spot** (cricket), **Snicko** (snickometer, cricket), **VAR** (football)
>  ends in a three-letter body part:
>      **battles·hip**, **ch·arm**, **nucl·ear**, **paperc·lip**
>  [Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) Universe superheroes: **Falcon**, **Hulk**, **Nebula**, **Vision**
>
>  Linking word: **HAWKEYE**

Wall 07:

> "house ...": **martin**, **proud**, **warming**, **wife**
>  "... hands": **clasp**, **fold**, **join**, **shake**
>  parts of a golf course with their last letter changed:
>     **bunked**/r, **Greek**/n, **rouge**/h, **ten**/e
>  ends in a synonym of old:
>     **outr·aged**, **pre·mature**, **stin·gray**, **st·ripe**
>
>  Linking word: **HOLD**

Wall 08:

> "Red ...": **alert**, **card**, **devils**, **[rum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Rum)**
>  Prepending an S makes a tennis term: (s)**ingles**, (s)**lice**, (s)**mash**, (s)**pin**
>  "... potato": **couch**, **jacket**, **new**, **sweet**
>  Letters of the Nato alphabet two letters short: **Bra**(vo), **Go**(lf), **Tan**(go), **Yank**(ee)
>
>  Linking word: **HOT**

Wall 11:

> Australian GKs: **Bosnich**, **Federici**, **Filan**, **Schwarzer*
>  contains a number: **fun·nine·ss**, **ne·two·rk**, **s·ten·t**, **w·eight·ed**
>  Months as first names:
>      April **Bowlby**, August **Diehl**, May **McAvoy**, June **Whitfield**
>  Harrison Ford characters: **Book**, **Kimble**, **Ryan**, **Solo**
>
>  Linking word: **JONES** (Brad, Indiana and January)

Finally, an observation:

> The walls seem to be sorted alphabetically by their linking word.

Comment: I think the "S" words have a tennis connection.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense.

Comment: 06 07 08 all fully correct :)

Comment: @Stiv but is 02 rot13(pbeerpg)?

Comment: Heh, yes that wall is one of the ones with _multiple_ sports groups... But 02 is now all correct. (And your last observation may prove helpful...)

Comment: Well, based on that observation, I think I've got them all, but I'm still missing a lot of groups.

Comment: I have no objection to theories being posted alongside completed connecting walls already discovered - my request in the question was more to deter content that would be best posted as comments rather than by itself in an answer...

Comment: I'll hold off posting more for the moment. Others seem to have fun with this, too, and I really, really should be cleaning the flat instead ...

Answer (score 6):

Ok, let's get this started with wall 09:

> UK Chancellors of the Exchequer:
>  Jeremy **HUNT**
>  Nigel **LAWSON**
>  John **MAJOR**
>  George **OSBORNE**
>
>  Ice hockey players (not sure if there's something more specific about these, knowing nothing about the sport):
>  Connor **MCDAVID**
>  Bobby **ORR**
>  Bobby **HULL**
>  Dickie **MOORE**
>
>  Words that rhyme:
>  **CIAO**
>  **FRAU**
>  **PLOUGH**
>  **WOW**
>
>  Homophones of question words:
>  **HOO**  (Who?)
>  **WATT** (What?)
>  **WEAR** (Where?)
>  **Y** (Why?)
>
>  And the linking word is **HOWE** (Geoffrey Howe for the chancellor and Gordie Howe for the ice hockey player).

Wall 14:

> Words for a short period of time:
>  **JIFFY**
>  **MINUTE**
>  **MOMENT**
>  **SHAKE**
>
>  Words that start with a trigonometric function:
>  **COSTCO**
>  **COTTAGE**
>  **SINCERE**
>  **TANGERINE**
>
>  Words that can be followed by strike:
>  **BIRD**
>  **COUNTER**
>  **GENERAL**
>  **HUNGER**
>
>  Staff at a boxing match:
>  **COACH**
>  **DOCTOR**
>  **PROMOTER**
>  **REFEREE**
>
>  And the linking word is **SECOND**

Wall 15:

> National Basketball Association presidents:
>  Walter **KENNEDY**
>  Larry **O’BRIEN**
>  Maurice **PODOLOFF**
>  David **STERN**
>
>  Medals:
>  **AIR**
>  **FIELDS**
>  **GEORGE**
>  **GOLD**
>
>  Fictional pirate captains:
>  **FLINT** (Treasure Island)
>  **HOOK** (Peter Pan)
>  **SPARROW**  (Pirates of the Carribean)
>  **SHAKESPEARE**  (Stardust)
>
>  Television fictional horses:
>  **CHAMPION** (Champion the Wonder Horse)
>  **FURY** (Fury)
>  **HERCULES** (Steptoe and Son)
>  **TORNADO** (Zorro)
>
>  And the linking word is **SILVER** (Adam Silver for the NBA, Long John Silver for the pirates, and from the Lone Ranger for the television series).

Comment: 09 correct :) For your sporting connection, that's the simplest connection, yes (and that's fine) - if interested: specifically, though, they are all multiple winners of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Ross_Trophy)...

Comment: 14 and 15 also correct :)

Answer (score 6):

Wall 01:

> **THE BIG**: Apple, Bopper [(J.P. Richardson)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bopper), Short ([movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Short_(film))), Sleep ([movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Sleep_(1946_film)))
>  **HITTING NOISES**: boff, pow, sock, thwack
>  **PREFIX TO ASIAN COUNTRY**: Chin(a), Phil(ippines), Sing(apore), Unit(ed Arab Emirates)
>  **BOARD GAMES**: [Deadwood](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/96713/deadwood), [Gunslinger](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1044/gunslinger), [Homesteaders](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/26566/homesteaders), [Revolver](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/76150/revolver) (board game connection)
>
>  Linking word: **BANG** (Bangladesh, [board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3955/bang))

Wall 03:

> **REPLACE VOWEL TO MAKE BIRD**: awl (owl), joy (jay), lurk (lark), stark (stork)
>  **QUARTER**: back, final, master, note
>  **CARD**: deal, jack, suit, trick (card game connection)
>  **FIRST 3 LETTERS ARE MONTH**: jane, junk, mark, nova
>
>  Linking word: **DECK** (duck)

Wall 04:

> **GREEK LETTER INSIDE**: a**phi**d, ea**rho**le, s**mu**g, ti**beta**ns
>  **APPLE**: Braeburn, Cameo, Fuji, Gala
>  **ROMAN**: Candle, Catholic, Holiday, Kemp
>  **MONOPOLY SQUARES**: (Jail) Break, (Chance) Encounter, (Go) South, (Just Visiting) This Planet ([book](https://neildegrassetyson.com/books/1998-07-just-visiting-this-planet/), [film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099909/), or [album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_Visiting_This_Planet)) (board game connection)
>
>  Linking word: **EMPIRE** (Boardwalk Empire)

Wall 12:

> **PRO PREFIX**: active, cure, fit, vince
>  **RUN**: dry, dummy, home, rat
>  **BOAT**: gun, life, pleasure, speed
>  **DECATHLON EVENTS**: hammer (throw), high (jump), pole (vault), shot (put) (sporting connection)
>
>  Linking word: **LONG** (jump)

Wall 16:

> **KICK**: bicycle, corner, free, goal (soccer sporting connection)
>  **IN A**: bind, fix, jam, pickle
>  **ON THE**: fence, ropes, run, take
>  **ANAGRAMS**: opts, post, stop, tops
>
>  Linking word: **SPOT**

Comment: @Stiv For 03, I had it correct initially, but I had a mental block and couldn't figure out what  "jack" had to do with "card" (duh).  I fixed it up now.

Comment: 01, 03, 12 and 16 fully correct :)

Comment: That suggests to me that something is wrong with your suggested solution... 'Bobby' is not a category I'm expecting to see...

Comment: It does indeed have a sporting link, but not with Bobby (since that was kinda used in the initial grid that C....... came from).

Comment: @Stiv I got stuck on the final answer after getting 3 of the categories because I thought the answer would be a state nickname.  There were two good ones that fit with "up" and "hand": "free" and "first".  But nothing fit with those for the 4th category.  I found "Bobby" versions of the 4 names, but that was a dead end.  I probably saw a few "Eddies" as well, but since I was fixated on "free" and "first" I totally ignored that as a possibility.  I also would have looked for the final word to be a last name for Eddie rather than a preceding word.  I had too many mental blocks!

Comment: I did debate using a word in the rot13(FGNGR) category that wasn't an actual nickname but a preceding word (in order to close off that dead end), but I was already really happy with the variety in the 4 walls I'd designed for that group so I left it... Apologies for your time spent in mental cul-de-sacs!

Answer (score 5):

Wall 5:

> **1. Words that can end with 'time'**:
>  EXTRA time, HALF time, INJURY time, OVER time (all terms used in sports)
>
> **2. Words that starts with a dynasties of China**:
>  **JIN**X ([Jin Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(1115%E2%80%931234))), **MING**LE ([Ming Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty)), **SUI**TE ([Sui Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_dynasty)), **TANG**Y ([Tang Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tang_dynasty))
>
> **3. Words that can be prepended with "don't give a " and means that you couldn't care less**:
>  don't give a DAMN, don't give a FIG, don't give a HOOT, don't give a TOSS
>
> **4. Words that can be appended with nail**:
>  (FINGER)NAIL, (HOB)NAIL, [JIMMY NAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Nail), RUSTY NAIL
>
> The linking word is **HANG**
>  (Hang time, [Han Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty), don't give a hang, [hangnail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangnail))

Wall 10:

> **1. Towns in Ayrshire, Scotland**:
>  KILMARNOCK, LARGS, SALTCOATS, TROON
>
> **2. Names end in plant names (specifically climbers)**:
>  CORNERS**HOP**, MONT**ROSE**, PR**IVY**, SICI**LIANA**
>
> **3. Cities in Orange County**:
>  BREA, CYPRESS, ORANGE, WESTMINSTER
>
> **4. Female BBC presenters (Sports connection)**:
>  Sue BARKER, Claire BALDING, Gabby LOGAN, Alex SCOTT
>
> Linking word is **IRVINE**
>  (It is a town in Ayrshire, its name ends in vine, it is a city in Orange County and Hazel Irvine is a BBC presenter.)

Wall 13:

> **1. Words related to standard time zones**:
>  ALASKA standard time, CENTRAL time, EASTERN time, PACIFIC time
>
> **2. Words that can be placed in front of the word bike**:
>  DIRT bike, [GHOST bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_bike), PUSH bike, EXERCISE bike
>
> **3. Words that start with the surname of a player in England's national team**:
>  **SAKA**GUCHI (Bukayo Saka), **SHAW**L, (Luke Shaw), **RICE**PAPER (Declan Rice), **POPE**YE (Nick Pope)
>
> All of the English football players can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England_national_football_team#Players).
>
> **4. Words that are the names of rock bands**:
>  KANSAS, BOSTON, KISS, RAINBOW
>
> The linking word is **MOUNTAIN**.
>  ([MOUNTAIN time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone), MOUNTAIN bike, there is an English player named [Mason Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_Mount), and there is band named [Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_(band)).)

Comment: 13 exactly right :)

Comment: Re 10 These are the correct groupings and hidden word. The plants are all specifically climbers. The 'show' you reference isn't actually a show but a movement or a hashtag - they are specifically all female sports presenters on the BBC.

Comment: @Stiv Oh, I mistakenly assumed it was a show because I read the word "new BBC season" over [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/mediacentre/mediapacks/change-the-game).  I have corrected it now (and also, made the necessary corrections for the plant one). Thanks.

Comment: Wall 05 exactly right, well done :) (10 also now correct)

Comment: @Stiv Not sure if it was an intentional trap but I got completely stuck on wall 10, despite having all the sets, because the four presenters have a much more specific connection, being four of the select group who have presented/hosted the BBC SPotY award show. So I was looking (unsuccessfully) for a fifth member of that group that could fit the other sets.

Comment: @fljx Not intentional. Since that was one of the harder categories I was hoping the other 3 groups might help justify the answer for that one...

Answer (score 5):

**Slightly partial** solution to Wall 04 which I hope is acceptable given that it's one of the last two holdouts:

> Apple varieties: BRAEBURN CAMEO FUJI GALA
>  Contain Greek letters: APHID EARHOLE SMUG TIBETANS
>  Roman ...: CANDLE CATHOLIC HOLIDAY KEMP
>  Synonyms of names of card or board games: BREAK (Snap), ENCOUNTER (Réunion), SOUTH (Australia?), THIS PLANET (Earth)
>  Extra word: EMPIRE.

I'm not entirely convinced by

> SOUTH (for which "Australia" isn't a great synonym, after all, but that is where the name comes from), I'm not 100% convinced by EARTH, though there are definitely games of that name, and I wonder whether I should be looking for all card games or all board games. (Dominion, the synonym for EMPIRE, is kinda both.)

Comment: You have the correct groupings and hidden word, but the definition behind the last group (board games related) is incorrect. This is one of the trickiest in the puzzle, I think, but also gettable... I'm sure someone will spot it :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm in a similar position with wall 05, except there I don't even have a semi-plausible explanation for the left-over group that I can use to justify posting :-).

Comment: (that is, I have three confident groups and a confident extra word, but the fourth group escapes me)

Comment: Ah, I see someone else has done 5 so that's OK. (And in fact they'd already done it long before I posted those comments. My apologies for being unobservant.)

Answer (score 4):

The Meta wall categories appear to be

> Words that precede ON: BANG, HANG, HOLD, SPOT

> Sportsmen named EDDIE: [CHARLTON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Charlton), [HOWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Howe), [IRVINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Irvine), [JONES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Jones_(rugby_union))

> Words that precede HAND: DECK, HOT, LONG, SECOND

> State Nicknames: EMPIRE (NY), HAWKEYE (IO), MOUNTAIN (WV), SILVER (NV)

The linking word is

> STEADY which can precede EDDIE, HAND, ON and STATE.

Comment: You're super close but maybe think differently about how to use your last category, and note the slightly different rule description in the preamble for the meta wall...

Comment: Thanks @Stiv think that I have it now. See the amendment.

Comment: That's it! We finally got there, people :) Thanks everyone for having a crack at this (it took a long time to design and test) - I hope it was enjoyable and not too daunting a prospect... I don't think I'll be making another one any time soon!

Comment: Give the green checkmark to him.

Comment: @1357924680a Mine’s a pretty minimal contribution, so I hope people upvote the other answers before mine.

Comment: I have now posted a (checkmarked) community wiki answer to compile all contributing answers into one post, with a consistent formatting so that readers can easily see all the information in one place. Each individual answer has earned my upvote (and my thanks for participating!).